# Spring RequestMapping annotation implementation

Tags: spring, annotations, bytecode, post-processing

can someone please tell me where I can find the source code that processes @RequestMapping annotation. I want to make a similiar annotation.

I know it's somewhere on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/

But i haven't found so far where the actual processing takes place.

Comment: [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java#L114](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java#L114)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply plug `@RequestMapping` text to the search field on the top of GitHub project page to see where that class is used.

Here is the direct link. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1204d2aef4afdefb4ba73c86565aab3f5b2a6931/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java

Comment: It is not the case now (after 6 years) :)